# Can't seem to add an anchor tag for an image after I added a hover effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a website to download wallpapers. On the home page, I want to create a hover effect on the image so I can add a "like" and "add" to the collection button.
Here's the reference: https://unsplash.com/
I have the hover effect that I want but I want to be able to click on the image so that the user can go to a download page. But I can't seem to add an anchor tag after I added the hover effect.

The HTML code for a single image:

```css
.card {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.image-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.image-overlay--blur {
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.image-overlay:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.image-overlay>* {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.image-overlay:hover>* {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card ml-4 bg-dark" style="width: 30rem;" data-aos="fade-left">
      <img src="img/1.png" class="card-img-top " alt="...">
      <div class="image-overlay image-overlay--blur">
        <div class="card-text">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-2">Like</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mr-2">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There is no anchor link in your code

Comment: If you look at the code in the example you provided, the image is contained in the anchor tag. Wrap your image in an anchor.

Comment: Yes i removed the anchor tag because it was'nt working. I had the image in an anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution without the anchor tag, use the onclick attribute on the image container like this:

```
<div class="image-overlay image-overlay--blur" onclick="window.open('image-link')">
```

This will open the indicated url inside the window.open() function in a new tab.
Use the second argument to open link in same tab.

```
<div class="image-overlay image-overlay--blur" onclick="window.open('image-link', '_self')">
```

Now if an anchor tag is required, do it like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="url here" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <div class="card ml-4 bg-dark" style="width: 30rem;" data-aos="fade-left">
      <img src="img/1.png" class="card-img-top " alt="...">
      <div class="image-overlay image-overlay--blur">
        <div class="card-text">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-2">Like</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mr-2">Add</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```